# Tkinter - Return column number of selected treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

How do I get the number of the column that is selected in a tkinter treeview?

Right now I'm using tree.focus() but it returns something like I001 or I00A and I have no idea how to convert that to a number.

I can't index the tree because there are multiple items with the same name in it, and I want to know the exact column the user clicks on.

What I expect is to click the first item and get the integer 0 back, etc.

Thanks, please ask questions if I was confusing...

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will allow us to assist you with you question. There is not any code to reproduce the problem. Without the MCVE it will be unlikely that you get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Here are docs](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html) for Treeview.

You have used the term "column" repeatedly, but when you say "multiple items with the same name" and refer to "first item" it sounds a lot like you're talking about rows.

If you want the column, you'll need to capture the click event using `treeview.bind("<Button-1>", callback)` or a variant of that. You would then use `treeview.identify_column` to get the column index based on the event's x location (keep in mind, per the docs, that if your columns are rearranged you may need to do some extra work). [Here are](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/events.html) [two links](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) if you need information on events.

If you were actually talking about rows, you can use `treeview.selection()` to get a list of iids of selected items, and then feed them into `treeview.index()` to get the 0-index of the row that you were talking about.